# PhpStorm PHPUnit Setup

Tags: vagrant, phpunit, phpstorm

I try to use Remote PHP and Remote PHPUnit in PhpStorm but I got this error:

[image: Error]

My settings are:

[image: PHPUnit Settings]

[image: PHP Settings]

Its a Vagrant server and on the server itself PHPUnit is working with the same files.

Why do I have `Cannot find PHPUnit in include path (.:/usr/share/php)`? I have nowhere a setting with this path.

Comment: Can you show the config for your remote interpreter? And what version of PHPStorm do you have?